# add top right corner a flag responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

How I can add like USA flag right top corner? It should be responsive.
Its similar like paper folded corner but in folded part is USA flag.
And flag in corner should be clickable

```css
#triangle {
        right: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        background-image: url('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/612hQjoIpCL._AC_SL1446_.jpg');
        border-top: 100px solid ;
        border-left: 100px solid transparent;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="flagCorner" id="triangle">
```

This didnt really work for me. I see ribbons everywhere but didnt work for my flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it differently using `clip-path`

```css
#triangle {
  background-image: url('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/612hQjoIpCL._AC_SL1446_.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="flagCorner" id="triangle"></a>
```

And with a shadow you can consider an extra wrapper:

```css
#triangle a{
  background-image: url('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/612hQjoIpCL._AC_SL1446_.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
}
#triangle {
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 5px red);
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"><a href="#" class="flagCorner" ></a></div>
```

Comment: Oh works correcly. But if I try to add box shadow. it doesnt show up or not working.